# Add Hyperlink to XLS Cell (via variable)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a hyperlink in XLS (from an MSAccess recordset) using a variable to reference the desired cell and value but I am struggling with syntax.

From MS site, the following works as expected:

```
With wks1
   .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _
   Address:="https://example.microsoft.com", _
   TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"
End With
```

I can write into the desired cell using variables and recordset values as follows:

```
wks1.Range("B" & r).Value = rs("Name" & n).Value

(where r = XLS cell, i.e., "B4", n = rs member, i.e., "Name5")
```

When I attempt to Add a hyperlink using the variable approach, it fails (Type Mismatch):

```
With wks1
   .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B" & r).value, _
   Address:="https://example.microsoft.com", _
   TextToDisplay:= rs("Name" & n).Value
End With
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Show code that declares and sets r and n and rs variables. Step debug - are variables getting values? I tested code and concatenation works. `.Value` is not necessary. Is this code behind Access?

Comment: Anchor is a "range or shape" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the *Range* object and go like this:

```vb
Public Function SetLink()

    Dim wks1    As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Anchor  As Excel.Range

    Dim r       As Long

    r = 9   ' Example.

    Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set Anchor = wks1.Cells(r, 1)

    With wks1
       .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Anchor, _
       Address:="https://example.microsoft.com", _
       TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"
    End With

    Set Anchor = Nothing
    Set wks1 = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Gustav, thanks for the tip.  Works just as expected.